# Ubuntu Server Syslog is cluttered with apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.net-snmp.snmpd"

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Is there anything to worry?
If not, how to stop these logs?

audit_printk_skb: 39 callbacks suppressed
Sep 27 06:27:02 Servername kernel: [7575458.811518] audit: type=1400 audit(1632713222.554:17386376): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.net-snmp.snmpd" name="/proc/13c/1286/net/snmp" pid=1286 comm="snmpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Comment: What is the rest of the line?

Comment: c/1286/net/snmp" pid=1286 comm="snmpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Comment: Hi, you should edit the question instead of just writing a comment. Editing the question will return your post to the homepage so everyone can see your additional information.